# How to get different string values depending on the locale?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which shows html files from assets folder. I would like to translate some files.
For example I have files in folder assets/fr for french users and in assets/en for others.

Here is the line which I want to change:

```
String htmlFileName = "m" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
```

So I want to get language of phone, if it's french I want to show files from /fr and if it's other show /en.

The modified version of this line will look like

```
String locale = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
    if locale=french
String htmlFileName = "m" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
    else 
String htmlFileName = "mn" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
    endif
```

Syntax is incorrect because I don't know how to do that. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Please used below Syntax**

```
        String locale = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
        if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("french")) {
            String htmlFileName = "m" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
        } else {
            String htmlFileName = "mn" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have once more question. How can I display `String locale` in a such textview: `TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
title.setText(What should I put here);`

Comment: please write like that :- title.setText(locale);  please Up-vote this answer.